# how to stop program execution after a condition becomes true

Tags: javascript, function

I would like my program to stop execution after a condition becomes true. I'm writing code that tests a user input against a randomly generated number, if the guess is equal to the number generated I would like to prevent the user from being able to enter any more values and instead get a message telling them they've won the game.

I have a simple form where the user enters their guess and clicks on a button to submit. The following is my function:

```
function parseGuess(guess){

var diff = Math.abs(generatedNumber - guess);

    if(diff >= 50){
            view.displayMessage("Ice cold");

        } else if (diff >= 30 && diff < 50){
            view.displayMessage("Cold");

        } else if (diff >= 20 && diff < 30){
            view.displayMessage("Warm");

        } else if (diff >= 10 && diff < 20){
            view.displayMessage("Hot");

        } else if (diff >= 1 && diff < 10){
            view.displayMessage("Very hot");

        } else if(guess === generatedNumber){
            gameOver = true; 
         view.displayMessage("Well done! You guessed the number in " + (controller.guesses + 1)+" guesses");

        }
```

}

parseGuess is invoked inside the controller object that is called when the user clicks the button: 
    var controller = {

```
        guesses: 0,

            processGuess: function(guess) {

            var count = document.getElementById("count");   

            //var diff = Math.abs(generatedNumber - guess); 



            console.log(gameOver);



            if (guess <=0 || guess >=101 || isNaN(guess) || guess == "")
                {   
                    return alert("Oops, please enter a number between 1 & 100");

                }


                parseGuess(guess); 
                this.guesses++;

                addListElement(guess); 
                count.innerHTML = this.guesses; //write the guess count into the span  


        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using `return`

Comment: How is `parseGuess` invoked? Do you want to completely remove the text input? Why don't you post a complete example?

Comment: I did and that didn't work. I put: return view.displayMessage("Well done! You guessed the number in " + (controller.guesses + 1)+" guesses");

Comment: I have a variable that I set to false when the user has guessed the number and then use this to test each time a number is entered - but this doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can return out of any function using `return` eg:

```
function parseGuess(guess){

var diff = Math.abs(generatedNumber - guess);

    if(diff >= 50){
            view.displayMessage("Ice cold");
            return false;
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle in context of your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/theodin/0e4mso4L/1/

Comment: How exactly does that solve the problem *"I would like to prevent the user from being able to enter any more values"*?

Comment: Like said earlier on I tried that and it just continues even after guessing the number.